# If $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \| x_{j+1} - x_j\| < \infty$ then is it Cauchy?

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be a normed space. Assume for $x = (x_1, x_2, ...)\in X$, $$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \| x_{j+1} - x_j\| < \infty.
$$
Then is $x = (x_1, x_2, ...)$ Cauchy sequence with respect to $\|. \|$? If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: $\|x_{n+m}-x_{n}\| \le \sum_{j=n}^{n+m-1}\|x_{j}-x_{j+1}\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\Vert x_{j+1}-x_j\Vert<\infty$$
then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=n}^\infty\Vert x_{j+1}-x_j\Vert=0$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists an integer $n$ such that
$$\sum_{j=n}^\infty\Vert x_{j+1}-x_j\Vert<\varepsilon$$
Hence for all positive integer $p$, we have:
$$\Vert x_{n+p}-x_n\Vert\leqslant\sum_{j=n}^{n+p-1}\Vert x_{j+1}-x_j\Vert\leqslant\sum_{j=n}^\infty\Vert x_{j+1}-x_j\Vert<\varepsilon$$
i.e. $x$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Can you give a bound on $\|x_{j+k}-x_j\|$ for $j$ sufficiently large, $k\ge 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For some $N_\varepsilon$, $$\sum \limits_{i=N_\varepsilon}^\infty \left\| x_{i} - x_{i+1} \right\| < \varepsilon.$$
Let $N_\varepsilon < a < b$. Then, by triangle inequality (why), $$\left\| x_a - x_b \right\| \leq \sum \limits_{i=a}^{b-1} \left\| x_i - x_{i+1} \right\| \leq \sum \limits_{i=N_\varepsilon}^
\infty \left\| x_i - x_{i+1} \right\| < \varepsilon.$$